# visiting France, Belgium and The Netherlands over the period of April 13-25, 2019. Holding multiple Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, standard-visitor-visas, romania

I'll be travelling to Europe next April 13-25, 2019. But I want to visit Romania and stay for a week in July 06-14, 2019. I am applyimg for a Schengen visa from the Embassy of India. Will it permit me to enter Romania?

Comment: @Traveller Not a duplicate. That question is about using a Schengen visa to enter Romania before Schengen; this question is the other way around.

Comment: Are you really applying for a Schengen Visa from the "Embassy of India"? I don't remember India becoming a member of the Schengen treaty...

Answer (score 0):

Romania is not yet a member of the Schengen zone, but intends to join.
In the mean time holders of a multiple entry Schengen Visa do not need to apply for a separate Romania visa.

The Romanian ministry of foreign affairs mentions this:

http://mae.ro/en/node/2040#null

> Starting July 11, 2014, in keeping with the provisions of Decision No
>   565/2014/EU, Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own
>   national visas, for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of
>   180 days the following:
>
> - The two or multiple entry short-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;

So if your Schengen Visa is a multi entry one, then you are ok to go.